# Passing typescript props into styled components results in 'No overload matches this call' problem

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

Working on this functional component, and switching from MUI `useStyles` to styled components. I thought from reading the docs that if you want to access the props inside styled components without getting typescript errors, you need to pass in the types like
``` const StyledDiv = styled.div<Types>``; ```

After doing this, I am getting an overload error from typescript inside the component using the styled component

```
import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
import PlanCard from 'components/composed/PlanCard';
import React from 'react';
import { IPlanType } from 'store/plans/plans.types';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import theme from '../../../theme';

export interface IPlansOverview {
  planTypes: IPlanType[];
  lifePlansList: string[];
  plansListMap: Record<string, string[]>;
  descMap: Record<string, string>;
}

const StyledGrid = styled(Grid)<IPlansOverview>`
  flex: ${(props) => (!(props.planTypes && props.planTypes.length === 1) ? '1' : 'initial')};
  width: ${(props) => (props.planTypes && props.planTypes.length === 1 ? '365px' : '100%')};
  ${theme.breakpoints.down('sm')} {
    flex: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
`;

const PlansOverview = ({ planTypes, lifePlansList, plansListMap, descMap }: IPlansOverview) => {
  return (
    <StyledGrid item>
      <Grid
        container
        spacing={4}
        justify={planTypes && planTypes.length === 1 ? 'flex-end' : 'space-between'}
      >
        // omitting the internal code as it's not really relevent...
        // I don't think?
      </Grid>
    </StyledGrid>
  );
};

export default PlansOverview;
```

On the `<StyledGrid item>` I have this error.

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Omit<Omit<Partial<Record<Breakpoint, boolean | GridSize>> & { alignContent?: GridContentAlignment; alignItems?: GridItemsAlignment; ... 6 more ...; zeroMinWidth?: boolean; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...> & IPlansOverview, never> & Partial<...>, "theme"> & { ...; } & { ...; }): ReactElement<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: Element; item: true; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Omit<Omit<Partial<Record<Breakpoint, boolean | GridSize>> & { alignContent?: GridContentAlignment; alignItems?: GridItemsAlignment; ... 6 more ...; zeroMinWidth?: boolean; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...> & IPlansOverview, never> & Partial<...>, "theme">': planTypes, lifePlansList, plansListMap, descMap
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: StyledComponentPropsWithAs<OverridableComponent<GridTypeMap<{}, "div">>, any, IPlansOverview, never, OverridableComponent<GridTypeMap<{}, "div">>, OverridableComponent<...>>): ReactElement<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: Element; item: true; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Omit<Omit<Partial<Record<Breakpoint, boolean | GridSize>> & { alignContent?: GridContentAlignment; alignItems?: GridItemsAlignment; ... 6 more ...; zeroMinWidth?: boolean; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...> & IPlansOverview, never> & Partial<...>, "theme">': planTypes, lifePlansList, plansListMap, descMapts(2769)
```

I looked at some similar issues on SO, but the solutions seemed to be implementing things the way I already have them. Curious if it's my typescript configuration.  I'm using @types/styled-components.

Please help, and thanks!

Comment: not sure it will work, but as Grid is a MUI component, I would make sure your IPlansOverview extends the GridProps from MUI. let's give it a try

Comment: Didn't fix the issue, but it was a good point. Did, make the change, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That error occurs because you are using `IPlansOverview` interface for the `StyledGrid` and for the `PlansOverview` component.

So as your `IPlansOverview` interface has no nullable properties, you are defining that `StyledGrid` needs to have all this properties, and then you should set it like that:

```
<StyledGrid item planTypes={xxx} lifePlansList={xxx} plansListMap={xxx} descMap={xxx}>
```

From what i can see, your `StyledGrid` just checks the `planTypes` prop. So what you can do is:

1. Create a new interface just for the `StyledGrid`:

```
export interface IStyledGridProps {
  planTypes: IPlanType[];
}
```

2. Define `StyleGrid`like this:

```
const StyledGrid = styled(Grid)<IStyledGridProps>`
 ...
`
```

3. Pass it in your `StyledGrid` :

```
<StyledGrid item planTypes={planTypes}>
   <Grid
      container
      spacing={4}
      justify={
         planTypes && planTypes.length === 1 ? "flex-end" : "space-between"
      }
   ></Grid>
</StyledGrid>
```

Comment: I tried this initially. No luck. I’m away from my computer right now, but tomorrow I’ll see if I can make a codepen. Not sure if I’ll get the typescript errors in there?